# How to apply persistent styles to rich text widgets between refreshes in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: class, ckeditor, apostrophe-cms

I am a beginner with Apostrophe and am trying to get my head wrapped around some of the concepts while also familiarizing myself with the entirety of what Apostrophe can do.

At the time being, I am building a marketing page. I have a rich text widget singleton defined as such:

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'introBlurb', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
            toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ],
            styles: [
            { name: 'H1', element: 'h1' },
            { name: 'H2', element: 'h2' },
            { name: 'H3', element: 'h3' },
            { name: 'H4', element: 'h4' },
            { name: 'P', element: 'p'},
            { name: 'H1 Center', element: 'h1', styles: {'text-align': 'center'} },
            { name: 'H2 Center', element: 'h2', styles: {'text-align': 'center'} },
            { name: 'H3 Center', element: 'h3', styles: {'text-align': 'center'} },
            { name: 'H4 Center', element: 'h4', styles: {'text-align': 'center'} },
            { name: 'P Center', element: 'p', styles: {'text-align': 'center'} },
            { name: 'H1 Right', element: 'h1', styles: {'text-align': 'right'} },
            { name: 'H2 Right', element: 'h2', styles: {'text-align': 'right'} },
            { name: 'H3 Right', element: 'h3', styles: {'text-align': 'right'} },
            { name: 'H4 Right', element: 'h4', styles: {'text-align': 'right'} },
            { name: 'P Right', element: 'p', styles: {'text-align': 'right'} }
            ]
            }) }}
```

CKEditor correctly displays all of the usable text styles in the editor dropdown, and the text that I input has the correct text-align applied to it. Typing while H1 Right is selected, for example, shoves text way to the right of the input box, as it should.

However, upon refresh (after ensuring it was saved), the text reverts to a left-justified style. I have tried the following:

- swapping the "styles" object within one of the elements for "attributes: {'class': 'textAlignRight'}"
- attaching "!important" to the text-align styles I've listed above
- removing all text-align CSS from my primary "site.less" file
- reconfiguring sanitizeHtml within an index.js file at lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text AND lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets
  ...as well as any and all combinations of the above.

Most of the above was gleaned from the discussion at https://forum.apostrophecms.org/t/using-styles-with-a-rich-text-widget/115

Due to my inability to nail this down, I have resorted to simply applying classes to the s containing the editable sections instead to control text-alignment. Surely this is not necessary, as I would prefer to give my site admin a way to align their own text, should they decide it looks better in the center as opposed to the left or right, or what have you.

If anybody has any suggestions or can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent copy-and-paste from webpages or apps from breaking the layout of your site, Apostrophe filters the markup that is submitted for rich text widgets.

You can adjust that filtering to allow things you want to allow without allowing junk through.

To do that, check out the [ApostropheCMS CKEditor HOWTO](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/howtos/ckeditor), in particular the coverage of how to configure `sanitize-html` for your project.

You could write:

```
// in your project level lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js file
module.exports = {
  sanitizeHtml: {
    allowedAttributes: {
      'h1': [ 'style' ]
      // etc. for other tags allowing this
    }
  }
};
```

But this would allow random CSS to be pasted. A better idea would be to define CSS classes like `center` for the kinds of text alignment you want and then use the `allowedClasses` feature of sanitize-html:

```
allowedClasses: {
  h1: [ 'center' ]
}
```

Then you have better control of what happens when users paste content in your site.

Comment: Tom, thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately that did not quite do the trick for me. Is there any way I have to tell Apostrophe to import/use the apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js file? I am not concerned with users copying and pasting, this is going to be an input-free webpage that is simply there to show information.

Comment: Tom is right, but you'll also have to change your style objects. Ex: `{ name: 'H1 Center', element: 'h1', styles: {'text-align': 'center'} },`
to `{ name: 'H1 Center', element: 'h1', attributes: { style: 'text-align: center'} },`. That said, a utility class like `.u-center` might be cleaner.

Comment: "Is there any way I have to tell Apostrophe to import/use the apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js file?" What would you be importing this for?

Comment: @alexbea , my apologies for the confusing terminology about "importing" the index.js file, I was just asking if there were any extra steps I had to do in order to get that index.js file recognized by the project outside of just creating my own apostrophe-rich-text-widgets directory containing the index.js file. I've copied your code with the corrected 'H1 Center' object (as well as created Tom's index.js file) and am still experiencing the issue - the typed text shows up correctly, centered in the editable section, but reverts to left-justification after refreshing.

Comment: Where exactly did you put the file?

Comment: I have the index.js file in the exact path you provided in your code snippet: lib/modules/apostrophe-rich-text-widgets/index.js

Comment: Check out this minimal test case I put together: https://github.com/abea/minimal-apos/tree/ckeditor-config. [The diff](https://github.com/abea/minimal-apos/compare/ckeditor-config)